# How to detect if (number + chars (not number))

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

How would I detect if I have this scenario, I would be getting this inputs

```
3b => allow
4b => allow
55b => allow
1111bbbb => allow
num45 => no !
```

and if I do allow given, I wold also like to remove all characters that are not numbers

```
3b => 3
555B => 555
11 => 11
```

I have tried to check if the given input is numeric or not, but this condition is out of scope of my knowledge.

Thanks for your time and consideration.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if the string begins with a number

```
!/^[0-9]/.match(@variable).nil?
```

if it does, get only the number part

```
   @variable = @variable.gsub(/[^0-9]/, '')
```

Comment: but it fails, For example  

"abfff45".gsub(/[^0-9]/i, '')
=> "45"

I want that to return to false, If the first character is not number

Comment: sorry, i only thought you needed the second part, i included the first part also

Comment: -1. It would give you `12` from `"random\n1bar2"`. The worst solution gets accepted. Bleh.

Comment: Kahm, if he checks if the string fits the first statement, and if it does, does the second and everything is alright

Comment: @Zippie, as demonstrated by the above matching string, the check has many flaws.

Comment: Okay, do you really think he would get a input like that? Maybe he would be the best person to answer that. Anyways i don't think it's the best (nor good for that matter) solution (you can see what i wrote in a comment on the answer below), nor did i accept my own answer, but seems to fit his requirements. Please, no need for arrogance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
/\A(\d+)[a-z]*\z/i
```

If the expression matches your desired number will be in the first capturing group.

Example at [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/JsVFhyGPFC). (It uses `^`/`$` instead of `\A`/`\z` just for the demonstration, you should use `\A`/`\z`.)

Comment: close, but "11" should return "11" not nil

Comment: @pguardiario, oh, that wasn't clear in the specs to me. Fixed.

Comment: Why use `[a-z]*\z`? It really doesn't improve the test. See @pguardiario's answer.

Answer (score 2):

This will look for integer + string and convert it to an integer. It will ignore a string + integer input.

```
input = '45num'

if input.match(/\d+[a-zA-Z]+/)
  result = input.to_i
end

result => 45
```

Comment: This is by far the best answer, my looks like *** compared to it :)

Comment: The question says: `num45 => no !` - I took this to mean it shouldn't match. But who knows?

Comment: Yes you're right! I've typed the input the wrong way round. The regex is correct though :) Updated.

Answer (score 1):

You really want to use: `str[/\A\d+/]` - This will give you the leading digits or nil.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I am no regex ninja but I think you could use: `^([\d]+)` to capture JUST the number. give it a try [here](http://regexpal.com/)

Comment: No problem. Had a mistake in my regex which is now fixed

Comment: also close but this will match "foo\n99"